# Removing ImageMosaic artefacts?

Tags: geoserver, image-mosaic

I have a rasters i want to publish it on Geoserver i do:

```
@echo off
set ext=.tif
set extout=.tif
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%G IN ('dir /b D:\OFP\*.tif') DO ("C:\Program Files\GDAL\gdalwarp" -r average -srcnodata 0  -s_srs "local srs proj" -t_srs EPSG:3857 D:\OFP\%%~nG%ext% D:\ofp_ave\%%~nG%extout%)
```

After publish as Image Mosaic, and got result:

[image]

There is white lines between rasters. I played with layer params:

[image]

But lines stand still.  When i open geotiffs in Qgis i do not see any lines.
How can i remove ut?

Comment: Common mistake is to reproject images first and make mosaic from the warped images. It would be better to mosaic first and reproject afterwards. Mosaic can be a virtual one created with gdalbuildvrt. However, also running gdalwarp with -tr and -tap often helps. From http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html `- tap (target aligned pixels) align the coordinates of the extent of the output file to the values of the -tr, such that the aligned extent includes the minimum extent. `

Comment: Want to try `-tap -tr` but i not clearly understand what resolution i gonna put in `-tr` parameter.

Comment: Check what the resolution is in some image you have warped and set it to a little bit lower value. Then you will not loose quality, nor create unnecessarily large files.